# How to make the regex not case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried these solutions but it did not work.

(/Y/g, "ʏ", "i");

(/Y/g, "ʏ"(?i));

I want to convert Y,y to ʏ using regex. Thank you.

Comment: Just use a flag: `/y/gi`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the flag `i` to denote case **i**nsensitivity

```
new RegExp(/Y/ig);
```

Or a less intuitive alternative

```
new RegExp(/Y|y/g);
```